# Bootstrapping Windows EC2 instance with cfn-init command failing due to 1641 exit code

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, bootstrap

I'm having trouble with my EC2 instance cfn-init script.

I'm attempting to have it install Powershell v5.   When I execute the command:

```
"command" : "C:\\cfn\\install\\Win8.1AndW2K12R2-KB3066437-x64.msu /quiet"
```

The problem I'm running into is that it installs successfully but returns an exit code of 1641, which is "ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_INITIATED".

This is what I want, but cfn-init seeing this as an error.

2015-11-17 21:09:21,118 P2464 [ERROR] Exited with error code 1641

Am I doing this wrong, or is there a way to have the package report back a different exit code?